# Platypus shell script does not prompt for "read" command

Tags: macos, shell

I have a shell script like this :

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "What's your favorite color ?"
read user_color
echo "You like $user_color"
```

Whatever the settings I try with Platypus, the prompt is never shown on execution, thus the variable is not defined and never displayed. Is this something possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read` requires a controlling terminal (or at least a usable standard input), presumably in your environment no such terminal/input exists and so `read` cannot read any information (and `echo` has no standard output to send data to, assuming you don't see that either).

This limitation is in the [platypus documentation](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/files/manpages/PlatypusDocumentation.html#812) and a workaround using CocoaDialog is [given there as well](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/files/manpages/PlatypusDocumentation.html#73).

Comment: Thanks for this, I got it working with NAME=`$CD standard-inputbox --title "Color" --no-newline --no-cancel --informative-text "What's your favorite color"`