# Allow Homebrew to install a package using Platypus

Tags: homebrew, platypus

I'm trying to create a point-and-click "application" for Mac which installs packages via Homebrew. At the moment, I'm using a shell script which is wrapped in a Mac "app" powered by Platypus.

I can install homebrew using Platypus by executing the following in the script which powers the Platypus app:

```
eval "$($brew_path/brew shellenv)"
```

This allows me to check for `which brew` without issue which is useful for checking whether casks have been installed via brew.

When I try to use brew to install a package via the Platypus app, the package downloads, but brew errors out when it attempts to actually *install* the app because sudo privileges are required for that to finish.

I'm still exploring whether I can get the Platypus app to accept user input. (See: [Platypus shell script does not prompt for "read" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408464/platypus-shell-script-does-not-prompt-for-read-command))  Assuming I can, is it possible to pass this input through to the brew command via bash?

Or, is this whole attempt a lost cause?